# How to enable shared folders on virtual box

Tags: tag

I have seen many different variations of instructions on how to do this but none are working for me. It was never this difficult with vmware but I am stuck with VB for now.

After installing the Virtualbox Guest Additions iso, I do get the ability to resize the screen (after installingit 2x) but nothing else. No shared folders, clipboard or drag and drop.

What things can I check to see why this doesn't work..

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you saying you are stuck with VB?  I've used a number of Virtual Machines.  I feel more comfortable with Virtual Box... it's the best for me.  You didn't mention what you tried and had problems with.  But most of what you need is in the GUI interface, even though you can also use the commandline options as well.  There's also Qemu as well as a number of virtual machines that have a modest fee.  Add what you did to setup your shared folder in VB. It'd be easy to see what you're doing wrong... so easy that specifying the steps would most likely automatically resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings.  Click on General (on the right,) select the Advanced tab.  In there you can enable shared clipboard and drag and drop.

See this [link](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-share-folders-between-guest-and-host-in-virtualbox/) to set up shared folders.

Comment: Thanks. I found someone who had the EXACT issue and the fix was to reinstall as a 32bit os. Then it started working.